# Detecting Windows Phone version in C++ or C++/CX

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

It seems that Windows Media Foundation works slightly different in Windows 8.1.

And we need to add some code that looks like this:

```
#if WINDOWS_81
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        MFStartup(MF_VERSION)
        );
#endif
```

How can we check to see what version of Windows Phone is running via C++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WINVER to see / control which version the build is targeting at command time. See [Using the Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx#setting_winver_or__win32_winnt).

```
// 0x0603 for Windows / Windows Phone 8.1
#if WINVER >= 0x0603
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        MFStartup(MF_VERSION)
        );
#endif
```

If the only reason is for the MFStartup check then you can leave out the conditional. It is required for 8.1, but it should work fine for 8.0.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I've already added a workaround with passing C# Environment version to C++/CX but this works much better.

Comment: Windows Phone is not listed on the page you cited. Where did you get the define for Windows Phone?